# arr = [a,b] choose a, x% of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to write a program with the following requirement.

`arr = ['a', 'b']`

How to write a python program which choose `a` from `arr` x% of time.
(For example 80% of time).

I have no idea how should I start. Please help.

I know `random.choice(arr)`. But it will give a random choice I can not make it biased.

Comment: Are there always only two elements?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon as of now only two.

Comment: python2.7 or 3?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz python 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 

np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], p=(.8, .2))
```

Comment: nice solution ;)

Comment: Or faster, for only two options: `['a', 'b'][np.random.random() > 0.8]`

Answer (score 2):

First, store your probability as a float. For example, 80% would be

```
prob = 0.8
```

Then, check if it is greater than `random()`:

```
arr[0] if random() < prob else arr[1]
```

Note that this also works in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

random.choices(['a', 'b'], weights=[0.8, 0.2], k=2)

Comment: For python >= 3.6